# How to use pandas groupby with a period of time to and find the average count over years within the same time period

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched far and wide, but haven't found a good way of doing this yet. I have a pandas dataframe with my own text messaging data. It has columns 'utctime', 'sender', 'recipient', and 'message'. What I would like to do is to group this by an arbitrary minute time period (e.g. 10 or 20 min) and then see, over multiple years, the amount of messages I send per this time period throughout one day.

The first few rows of the data look like this, and this extends for 2 more years:

```
                        utctime  sender   recipient     message
0 2016-11-25 18:00:25.877000+00:00  Person1  Me            message1
1 2016-11-25 18:50:58.694000+00:00  Person2  Me            message2
2 2016-11-25 18:54:41.871000+00:00  Me       Person2       message3
3 2016-11-25 18:54:58.583000+00:00  Person2  Me            message4
4 2016-11-25 19:01:19.694000+00:00  Me       Person2       message5
```

What is what is the best way to do this so I can see my own text messaging frequency in 20 minute increments from 00:00 to 23:40?

So far what I do is have another function that collapses the times into a single day:

```
def time_of_day(data, tz_info):
    utctime = data.utctime.dt.tz_convert(tz_info)
    data['timeofday'] = pd.to_datetime({'year': 2017,
                                        'month': 1,
                                        'day': 1,
                                        'hour': utctime.dt.hour,
                                        'minute': utctime.dt.minute,
                                        'second': utctime.dt.second})

    return data
```

Which I then group by using a custom grouper:

```
sf = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
timedelta = '10min'
grouper = pd.Grouper(key='timeofday', freq=timedelta)
data = time_of_day(data, sf) # data is returned in time of day for tz

freq = data.groupby(grouper).count()
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: please accept and upvote if the answer is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need to extract the hours and minutes from 'utctime', categorize the minutes in `bins` and perform `groupby` on hours and minute_bins for the `count` of messages:

```
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['utctime']).dt.hour
df['Minute'] = pd.to_datetime(df['utctime']).dt.minute

df['minute_bins'] = pd.cut(df['Minute'], bins=(-0.01,20,40,60), labels=('0 < 20', '20 < 40', '40 < 60'))

df.groupby(['Hour', 'minute_bins'])['message'].count()

print(df)

Hour  minute_bins
18    0 < 20         1
      40 < 60        3
19    0 < 20         1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Cut was really what I wanted. However, do you know how you would put in the bins for a series of datetime objects?

Comment: Thanks. What would the bins be?

Comment: To be honest, your implementation works, but I still like the 'timeofday' series that I create, as then I can do more operations on it with respect to time zones etc, and then plotting using datetimes has a lot of flexibility and works well with matplotlib. So I would like to do something like `pd.cut(df['timeofday'], bins=(4)`, which works, but instead of putting the number of bins, I'd like to put the actual datetimes of the edges. But that does not work when I try datetime objects. When I use 4 for the bins, the first bin edge looks like `1.48322871e+18` (using the retbin option of cut).

Comment: Please post a new question with the desired output and a link to this question.